# Access a Views Subviews from ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `ViewController` and a `View` in separate files.
In the `ViewController` I add the View like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

        mainView = [[MainView alloc] init];
        [self setView: mainView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

In that `mainView` there is a label, added as `SubView`. I would like to change the labels text from my controller. How would I do that?

I can't figure out how to access the label from the controller.

Comment: Is MainView your own subclass of UIView?

Comment: Has the label been declared publicly using a property?

Comment: MainView is my Subclass of UIView.
I just declared the label in this Views .h file, but not as a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label needs to be exposed in the MainView as e.g. a property.

Then you can access that property like:

```
[[(MainView *)[self view] labelProperty] setText: @"foo"];
```

Or more readable:

```
MainView *mainView = (MainView *)self.view;
mainView.labelProperty.text = @"foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

If `mainView` has only the label as a subview and *no other subviews* you can easily access the label with

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[mainView.subviews objectAtIndex:0];
```

and then set its text like this:

```
label.text = @"your text";
```

That is the "quick and dirty" way.

---

**A much better solution** is to create a `property` in your `ViewController`for each subview that you want to modify. CTRL+drag the label to your `ViewController.h` file and Xcode should automatically add the line

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

Then you can easily access the label from anywhere in your `ViewController` with

```
label.text = @"your text";
```

Comment: The label must then be always the first subview of mainView - any change to the view hierarchy will break this code.

Comment: That is correct. The second solution which is pretty much the same that you and @msk suggested is much better and should be used. The first solution is the quick and dirty way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your edit. If I could mark several answers as accepted I would do it, I marked Alexanders because it was the first I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

In MainView.m tag your label where you are creating it

```
yourLabel.tag = 'urlb'
```

In your ViewController

```
UILabel *lbl = (UILabel *)[mainView viewWithTag:'urlb'];
[lbl setText: @"what is the problem"];
```

Comment: Thank you. This is probably what tags are for and looks nice and clean, but for now I go with Alexanders answer because it fits better for the task I am facing right now.